# Is $F(2)-F(-2)$ the same thing as $f(2)-f(-2)$?

Tags: calculus

[image: Picture of problem and graph] I thought that they were the same thing and that I would just use the graph numbers but the answer is not $4$ so apparently I'm wrong.

Based on the picture, we have $f$ to be the linear function on $[-2,-1]$ given by $f(-2)=-2$ and $f(-1)=0$. And $f$ to be the linear function on $[-1,2]$ given by $f(-1)=0$ and $f(2)=2$.

Comment: Just to check you understand: can you define the *antiderivative* of a function?

Comment: Please refer back to the answer you received to the closely related question given the same graph:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003652/how-do-i-begin-to-solve-this-integral.  Please don't dump your homework problems on this site.  You need to apply what you are learning (ie, apply what you learned earlier) to similar questions.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. That's why they bothered not only using two different symbols, but asking you as well.

Comment: @PatrickStevens the opposite or inverse of a derivative?

Comment: … No, not really. It's related to integration. You should go back and look up what your course has said about integration and antiderivatives.

Comment: @amWhy I am trying but they are different questions and I'm not seeing how the other question relates bc it was talking about doing chain rule, so I dont know how to apply that knowledge to this question.

Comment: @KhaylaWilliams $f$ and $F(x)=\int_{-2}^x f(t)\ dt$ are different functions, not the same in general.

Comment: That answer explained how to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, so you checked off that homework problem done for you, but didn't bother to learn from it or review your notes or the text on the FTC.  Since someone did your work for you earlier, you asked this question hoping someone would do it for you, this time too.  If this is how you handle homework, you'll fail your exams.

Comment: $F(2)-F(-2) = \int_{-2}^2 f(x) \ dx$ which equals the signed area between the curve and the x-axis over the interval.

Comment: @Valerin thank you for clarifying that they were two separate functions, i didnt clearly understand that until now. Now, I understand how the F(b)-F(a) part of the FTC applies here.

Comment: @amWhy  In my notes, my teacher had wrote something connecting F(b)-F(a) to f(b)-f(a) saying that they were equal and so that was my presumption. I see now that I should go back and ask her to clarify that concept. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No problem, Khayla.  Thanks for your work here in trying to understand this subject matter.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @KhaylaWilliams I have updated my answer for you. Please consider accept one of the anwers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Long way... Notice that $f$ is a linear function on $[-2,-1]$ and $[-1,2]$ so you can explicitly find it. Then you can antiderivate (integrate) $f$ on the desired interval.

So you have $$f(x)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}2x+2 &\mathrm{if}& -2\leq x\leq -1 \\ \frac{2}{3}x+\frac{2}{3} &\mathrm{if}& -1\leq x\leq 2 \end{array}\right. $$

Then you can integrate (antiderivate) $f$ and evaluate as needed.

You could use the following to compute: $$F(2)-F(-2) = \int_{-2}^2 f(x)dx = \int_{-2}^{-1} 2x+2\ dx + \int_{-1}^{2} \frac{2}{3}x+\frac{2}{3} dx$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique antiderivative of $f$, but for any number $a \in (-2,2)$ the quantity
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$$
is the area (with sign) of the portion of plane between the graph of $f$ and the horizontal axis. Thus
\begin{align*}
F(2)-F(-2) & = \int_a^2 f(t)\,dt - \int_a^{-2} f(t)\, dt \\
& = \int_a^2 f(t)\,dt + \int_{-2}^a f(t)\, dt \\
& = \int_{-2}^2 f(t)\, dt.
\end{align*}
This area is the sum of the areas (with sign) of two triangles and corresponds to $-1+3=2$. On the other hand, $f(2)-f(-2) = 4$.